# On Click of RadioGroup how to Show Preference

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to create a list of `RadioButtons` to click on a Preference. I did the radio buttons in this way:

```
<RadioGroup>
       <Preference android:key="ex" android:summary="Example" android:title="Example"/>
    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioSex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_male" 
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_female" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

After, in the Java file

```
Preference ex;
ex = (Preference) this.findPreference("ex");
ex.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

});
```

After this I do not know how to do. You can post a code to click on the preference displays a list of radio buttons? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box RadioGroup preference available. You would need to write one, by extending DialogPreference class.

Create a separate layout file (/res/layout/pref_radiogroup.xml) with the Dialog content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />
    </RadioGroup>

</FrameLayout>
```

Create your RadioGroupPreference class which will extend DialogPreference.

```java
public class RadioGroupPreference extends DialogPreference {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;

    public RadioGroupPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_radiogroup);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        View root = super.onCreateDialogView();
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) root.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        setSelectedValue(getPersistedString("Male"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (!positiveResult) {
            return;
        }

        if (shouldPersist()) {
            String valueToPersist = getSelectedValue();
            if (callChangeListener(valueToPersist)) {
                persistString(valueToPersist);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getString(index);
    }

    private void setSelectedValue(String value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof RadioButton) {
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) view;
                if (radioButton.getText().equals(value)) {
                    radioButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private String getSelectedValue() {
        int radioButtonId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonId);
        return (String) radioButton.getText();
    }

}
```

Now you only have to add your custom preference to your preference screen.

```xml
<com.package.RadioGroupPreference
    android:summary="Radio Group Preference Summary"
    android:title="Radio Group Preference"
    android:key="preference_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/radio_male" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand. How should I do? Could you be more precise maybe even putting the sample code?